# Module does not provide an export named default - compiled typescript module

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, module

I'm developing a node npm module in typescript, and after I compile it to commonjs and try to import it, I get the error: `SyntaxError: The requested module 'woo-swell-migrate' does not provide an export named 'default'`

[image]

But... it *does* have a default export. Here is the compiled index.js file:

```js
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const woocommerce_rest_api_1 = __importDefault(require("@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api"));
const swell_node_1 = __importDefault(require("swell-node"));
const path_1 = __importDefault(require("path"));
class WooSwell {
    /**
     *
     * @param config - required params for connecting to woo and swell
     *
     * @param dirPaths - directory paths to store json files and images in
     * @param dirPaths.data - directory to store json files in
     * @param dirPaths.images - directory where wordpress image backup is stored
     */
    constructor(config, dirPaths) {
        this.swell = swell_node_1.default.init(config.swell.store, config.swell.key);
        this.woo = new woocommerce_rest_api_1.default({
            consumerKey: config.woo.consumerKey,
            consumerSecret: config.woo.consumerSecret,
            url: config.woo.url,
            version: config.woo.version
        });
        this.wooImages = {};
        this.paths = {
            wooImageFiles: dirPaths.images,
            wooImageJson: path_1.default.resolve(dirPaths.data, 'woo-images.json'),
            wooProducts: path_1.default.resolve(dirPaths.data, 'woo-products.json'),
            swellCategories: path_1.default.resolve(dirPaths.data, 'swell-categories.json')
        };
    }
    /**
     * gets all records from all pages (or some pages, optionally) of endpoint
     *
     * @param endpoint - example: '/products'
     *
     * @param options - optional. if not provided, will return all records from all pages with no filters
     *
     * @param options.pages - supply a range of pages if not needing all - example: { first: 1, last: 10 }
     *
     * @param options.queryOptions - Swell query options, limit, sort, where, etc. See https://swell.store/docs/api/?javascript#querying
     *
     * @returns - record array
     */
    async getAllPagesSwell(endpoint, options) {
        const res = await this.swell.get(endpoint, options === null || options === void 0 ? void 0 : options.queryOptions);
        let firstPage = (options === null || options === void 0 ? void 0 : options.pages.first) || 1;
        let lastPage = (options === null || options === void 0 ? void 0 : options.pages.last) || Object.keys(res.pages).length;
        let records = [];
        for (let i = firstPage; i <= lastPage; i++) {
            const res = await this.swell.get(endpoint, Object.assign(Object.assign({}, options === null || options === void 0 ? void 0 : options.queryOptions), { page: i }));
            records.push(...res.results);
        }
        return records;
    }
    /**
     * gets all records from all pages of endpoint
     *
     * @param endpoint example: 'products'
     *
     * @param options - optional.
     *
     * @param options.pages - supply a page range if not loading all pages { start: 10, end: 15 }
     *
     * @returns - record array
     */
    async getAllPagesWoo(endpoint, options) {
        var _a, _b;
        const res = await this.woo.get(endpoint);
        const firstPage = ((_a = options === null || options === void 0 ? void 0 : options.pages) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.first) || 1;
        const lastPage = ((_b = options === null || options === void 0 ? void 0 : options.pages) === null || _b === void 0 ? void 0 : _b.last) || parseInt(res.headers['x-wp-totalpages']);
        const records = [];
        for (let i = firstPage; i <= lastPage; i++) {
            records.push(...(await this.woo.get(endpoint, { page: i })).data);
        }
        return records;
    }
}
exports.default = WooSwell;
```

It's there... right at the bottom. `exports.default = WooSwell`.
So why am I getting this error?

Here is my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "woo-swell-migrate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "test": "jest --config jestconfig.json"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "es2017": "^0.0.0",
    "image-size": "^1.0.1",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.35",
    "swell-node": "^4.0.9",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mime-types": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.0",
    "@types/woocommerce__woocommerce-rest-api": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.31",
    "jest": "^28.0.3"
  }
}
```

and my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*"]
}
```

Comment: just as an experiment.. can you try removing `"type": "module"` and give it a try!!!

Comment: if I remove "type":"module" and try to import the package, I get `TypeError: WooSwell is not a constructor` error. This is why I tried adding type:module in the first place... not sure why this error happens either, since it is clearly a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`exports.default` is exporting a member named `default`, sort of like this (invalid because `default` is a keyword):

```
export const default = someValue;
```

You can try using an import wildcard:

```
import * as WooSwellMigrate from "woo-swell-migrate";

const WooSwell = WooSwellMigrate.default; // access the exported member named "default"
```

But if it's within your reach, you should change how `woo-swell-migrate` is built! Try to use the ESM module system instead of CommonJS in its `tsconfig.json`.